create_date and modify_date for sys.objects in MSSQL shows same date
I am trying to figure out when is the create date of a user defined object in the database.
but when I ran a select query on sys.sysobjects, it seems create_date is the same as modify_date.
Is this by design in SQL Server?  I am using SQL Server 2016.

sys.sysobjects or sys.objects? At least on my edition, the sys.sysobjects does not contain create_date and modify_date columns - but sys.objects does.

I assume you are actually talking about sys.objects view, and not sys.sysobjects.
It seems like the modify_date is set to create_date until some other changes to table are made (which is pretty common pattern). According to documentation, the modify_date is:

Date the object was last modified by using an ALTER statement. If the object is a table or a view, modify_date also changes when an index on the table or view is created or altered.

This would also mean that (for example) inserting and updating data does not count - only changes to the structure of table (well, and indexing).
Demo (Fiddle):
DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS MyTable;

CREATE TABLE MyTable (Id INT);

SELECT 
  'after CREATE', 
  [name], 
  create_date, 
  modify_date, 
  [Same?] = IIF(create_date = modify_date, 'same', 'different')
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')

/*Let's wait a bit, to make potential differences more obvious.*/
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
  
INSERT INTO MyTable(Id)
VALUES (1), (2);

SELECT 'after INSERT - does not change the modify_Date', 
  [name], 
  create_date, 
  modify_date, 
  [Same?] = IIF(create_date = modify_date, 'same', 'different')
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')

ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD [Name] VARCHAR(50);

SELECT 'after ALTER', 
  [name], 
  create_date, 
  modify_date, 
  [Same?] = IIF(create_date = modify_date, 'same', 'different')
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')

